# chrome extension's content script not working in google, youtube pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension. When the user clicks my extension's icon (browserAction) the content script appends an extra div to the body of the open page(current tab). It works fine in all the sites except google's search page and youtube. I'm not getting any error message or anything. It simply wont give any response.

This is my code in **content.js**:

```
alert('sdsd');
$('body').append("<div id='popup'>My extension name</div>");
```

I've put the alert for testing purpose. So when extension is toggled it should show an alert message followed by appending the div to body, ideally! But it wont for these 2 sites.

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

**manifest**

```
{
    "name": "My first extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
    "content_scripts": [{
            "all_frames": true,
            "css": ["style.css"],
            "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]
        }],
    "permissions": [ "tabs","http://*/*" ],
    "browser_action": { "name": "test" },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"jquery.min.js"},function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"content.js"});
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Youtube's page, $ is overwritten and isn't jQuery. It's

```
bound: function ()
{
    return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments)
}
```

So your code makes an exception as there `document.getElementById('body')` is `undefined`.

You should try using [noConflict()](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

**EDIT :**

Why aren't you simply listing `jQuery.min.js` and your `content.js` in the `content_scripts` instead of injecting them programmatically. This would avoid conflicts.

**EDIT 2 :**

Now that you use content scripts, you should use [communication as described here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) to send from `background.js` to the content script the instruction to show the alert.

**EDIT 3 :**

Another solution would have been to use programmatic injection (as you initially did) and not use jquery, `$('body').append("<div id='popup'>My extension name</div>");` being translated in vanilla JS to

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'popup';
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = "My extension name"​;​
```

But it's generally cleaner (and requires less permissions) to avoid programmatic injection.

Comment: I tried jQuery.noConflict(); But no use. Also why isn't the simple js alert not working?

Comment: How are you executing your script ? Are you injecting it  ? Can you write your manifest in the question ?

Comment: Now both jquery.min.js and content.js are listed in manifest under content_scripts section. But now the content.js is being executed on page load. How should background.js be edited so that content.js runs only on onClicked event? Could you please help me on that too?

Comment: The DOM is still accessible from a content script. See edit (not tested).

Comment: I dont know if my statement was not clear enough. I want the alert and append to be run when onClicked eventHandler of *background.js* is called. That is, when user clicks extension icon. Not on body click. Im hoping the call should be put somewhere in here: chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener. Isn't it?

Comment: Your statement wasn't really confusing... I just forgot the context in between ^^ I edited.

Comment: Let me check that documentation. Meanwhile thanks for your help. +1